# I'm trying to display multiple random non repeating images from a folder but I get blank images

Tags: php, image, random

Hi I'm totally new at php and I put this script together modifying other scripts ... I'm trying to display multiple random non repeating images from a folder and it basically works except sometimes instead of an image I get a "blank" anyone can explain me why?

```
<?php

$imagesDir = 'images/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$imageList = range(0,count($images));
shuffle($imageList);
$image_idx = 0;

        echo'
<div class="main">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
</div>';

echo'
<div class="main">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
</div>';

echo'
<div class="main">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
</div>';

echo'
<div class="main">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
</div>';

echo'
<div class="main">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
</div>';

echo'
<div class="main">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
</div>';

echo'
<div class="main">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
<img src="' . $images[$imageList[$image_idx++]]. '" style="height:auto;width:33.33%;float: left">
</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Blank page without any data? If so, do you have errors enabled? Try returning variables with var_dump or error_log.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use var_dump($a); die(); to interrupt the script and see what is wrong with your variables.
2. Read about [loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types.htm) in PHP
3. Read about [principles](https://dzone.com/articles/software-design-principles-dry-and-kiss) of programming (DRY KISS)